# Javascript copy by value using $.extend, but only an object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, zepto

I am trying to copy a property by value so that different instances can modify it separately. My understanding is that using jQuery or Zepto's $.extend is a great way to do 'copy by value'. It is not working in my situation and I'd like to understand why. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
var c = [ {'purple' : 1}, { 'red':2 } ]
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c }
var doWork = function(passX) {
  var inY = $.extend({},passX);
  inY.colors[0].selected = true;
  return inY;
}
var y = doWork(x);

console.log( x.colors[0].selected );// true, but I think it should be undefined
console.log( y.colors[0].selected );​// true
```

I feel like I might be missing something really central. Can I not extend from the same object to do a copy? Is there something confounding about the function argument scope?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfnyp/5/

EDIT: The answer to my confusion, as @Niko points out, is that deep copy makes copy-by-value versions of all child properties. I thought deep vs shallow copy just meant how many properties deep the copy went. Oops.

EDIT AGAIN: Deep copy is troublesome in Javascript. JQuery has it, but Zepto and Underscore do not. Some describe it as impossible to implement well. To implement this for my problem, I have created this solution which relies on knowing the structure of the object. I believe this is the correct answer for me, though it is clunky.

```
var c = [ {'purple' : 1, 'selected':false }, { 'red':2 } ]
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c }
var doWork = function(passX) {
  var inY = $.extend({},passX);
  inY.colors = $.extend([], passX.colors);
  for (var i = 0; i < passX.colors.length; i++) {
    inY.colors[i] = $.extend({}, passX.colors[i]);
  }
  inY.colors[0].selected = true;
  return inY;
}
var y = doWork(x);

console.log( x.colors[0].selected );
console.log( y.colors[0].selected );
```

Comment: you have 2 absolute same objects -- `var x = y =...` when you assign object to a var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x = y` makes x and y reference the same object, therefore `y.colors` also overwrites `x.colors` - the `$.extend()` is pretty useless in this case.

```
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };
var y = $.extend(true, {}, x); // <-- first param "true" = make deep copy,
                               //     because otherwise "x.colors === y.colors"
```

The deep copy is required, because an array is also an object and therefore copied by reference when doing a shallow copy.

Or with the new code:

```
var inY = $.extend(true, {}, passX); // deep copy = also copy mod.colors by value
```

Comment: Exactly -- no need to extend as x = y

Comment: sorry, the example is bad. the objects are the same reference, but because they are passed as function arguments. Clarifying the example...

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Yes, but the deep copy still solves that problem (in your example code, x and y are different objects, but the array they contain is still a single one - they just both contain a reference to it, so you need a deep copy to ensure that it is copied by value): http://jsfiddle.net/n6fzV/

Comment: @Niko: so without deep copy it still copies the properties, but only by reference? I thought it would leave deep things undefined. Reference would explain everything.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Yes, a shallow copy copies everything from A to B, but if A contains a reference to an object (e.g. an array), it just copies the reference. A deep copy also makes true copies of the objects in A, and of objects in those objects, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
var c = [ {'purple' : 1}, { 'red':2 } ]
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };
var y = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };

y.colors = $.extend([],x.colors);

x.colors[0].selected = true;

console.log( x.colors[0].selected ); // true
console.log( y.colors[0].selected ); // now it's an error because y.colors[0] is undefined
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9D6ra/)

Comment: there has some error in your code when i try in firebug console:  with(_FirebugCommandLine){
var c = [ {'purple' : 1}, { 'red':2 } ]
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };
var y = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };

y.colors = $.extend([],x.colors);

x.colors[0].selected = true;

console.log( x.colors[0].selected ); // true
console.log( y.colors[0].selected );â€‹
};

Answer (score 1):

It's not the copy that's causing this, it's the `var x = y = {`.  You're setting `y` to an object, then setting `x` to `y`.  That causes `x` and `y` to point to the same object.

You need to set the object to one of the variables, then copy it to the other.

```
var x = { 'name': 'my obj', 'colors': c };
var y = $.extend({}, x);
```

Comment: The objects are passed in functions in the real use case so they do refer to each other. I'll clarify the example.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is because the variables `x` and `y` point to the same object. By setting `y.colors` to a new value, you will get that when accessing `x.colors`. That `$.extend([],x.colors)` is a copy of the original `c` does not matter here.

But it even would not work if `x` and `y` were different objects with different `colors` arrays. Using

```
var purple = {purple: 1}, red = {red: 2};
var colors = [purple, red];
var copy = $.extend([], colors);
```

then `copy[0]` would still point to `purple` as just as `colors[0]` does. You might want to use the [`deep` option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN):

```
var x = {name:'my obj', colors:[{purple: 1}, {red:2}]};
var y = $.extend(true, {}, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `$.extend` can perform a deep copy. All you have to do is add a new parameter in the first position as `true` -- it flags the *deep copy mode* -- and shift the remaining parameters right.

```
var o1 = {"a": "AA", "n": 11, "o": {"k0": "v0", "k1": "v1"}};
var oz = $.extend(true, {}, o1)
oz.o.k0 = 99;

dump(o1); // {a:"AA", n:99, o:{k0:"v0", k1:"v1"}}
dump(oz); // {a:"AA", n:99, o:{k0:99, k1:"v1"}}
```